# Edit SQL submissions PHP and Update data

Tags: php, mysqli

OK, so here is the problem now, the edit page doesn't prepopulate the fields that have already been filled out, nor does the update button actually update the db. Here is the code for the edit page.

```
$query = "SELECT orderNumber, customerName, salesRep, DatePicker, shipMethod, trackingNumber, StatusCheck, Price FROM Orders WHERE id = '$id'";
$result = @mysqli_query($query);

mysqli_fetch_object($result);
?>
<form name="update order" method="post" action="edit.php?a=edit&id=<? echo($ID) ?>&update=1">
  <table width="50%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr> 
      <td width="50%">Order Number</td>
      <td><input name="orderNumber" type="text" id="orderNumber" value="<? echo($row->orderNumber) ?>"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
      <td>Customer Name</td>
      <td><input name="customerName" type="text" id="customerName" value="<? echo($row->customerName) ?>"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
      <td>Sales Rep</td>
      <td><input name="salesRep" type="text" id="salesRep" value="<? echo($row->salesRep) ?>"></td>
         <tr> 
      <td>Must Ship By</td>
      <td><input name="DatePicker" type="text" id="DatePicker" value="<? echo($row->DatePicker) ?>"></td>
         <tr> 
      <td>Shipping Method</td>
      <td><input name="shipMethod" type="text" id="shipMethod" value="<? echo($row->shipMethod) ?>"></td>
         <tr> 
      <td>Tracking Number</td>
      <td><input name="trackingNumber" type="text" id="trackingNumber" value="<? echo($row->trackingNumber) ?>"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
      <td>Status</td>
      <td><input name="StatusCheck" type="radio" name="status" value="PROCESSING"> PROCESSING<br><input name="StatusCheck" type="radio" name="status" value="PROCESSING"> PICKED<br><input name="StatusCheck" type="radio" name="status" value="PROCESSING" value="<? echo($row->StatusCheck) ?>"> SHIPPED<br>  value="<? echo($row->StatusCheck) ?>"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
      <td colspan="2"><div align="center">
          <input name="hiddenField" type="hidden" value="update">
          <input name="add" type="submit" id="add" value="Update">
        </div></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  </form>
<?php

?>
```

Thank you all in advance!

Oops, forgot the UPDATE part

```
}else{
$query = "UPDATE Orders SET orderNumber= '$orderNumber, customerName= '$customerName', DatePicker= '$DatePicker', shipMethod= '$shipMethod', trackingNumber= '$trackingNumber', Status= '$status' timestamp = NOW() WHERE id = '$id';
$result = @mysql_query($query);
if(!$result){
   echo('Error updating item: ' . $mysql_error());
   exit();
}else{
   mysql_close($link);
   echo('Update successful!');
 }
```

Comment: where do you think the update should happen? I mean theres no `UPDATE` or `INSERT` statement at all

Comment: `$row` is not defined in your code. looks like you are tying to glue different things togeather with out understanding them

Comment: I forgot to add the update. And $Row is defined, it is just not in this code sample, it is in the overall full code - It is a viewer that selects data from the db and then displays it in a table with an edit link, that part works fine.

Comment: don't bother asking incomplete questions. " the edit page doesn't prepopulate the fields that have already been filled out," or "It is a viewer that selects data from the db and then displays it in a table with an edit link, that part works fine" they are are contridictory

Comment: missing quote in update, see the colour highlighting

Comment: Sorry for all the questions and stupidity @Dagon but I am real new to this, and this update part wasn't taught to me very well. But, is it possible to just have the edit page return only the fields that need to be 'updated at a later time'? And how do I link the 'update' button to the UPDATE sql script?